# Android Junit Test Bitmap Resources

Tags: java, android, junit4

```
public class JamTest {
Explosions EX = new Explosions(null);
private List<Bitmap> expList ;
Context mtx;


@Before
public void setUpList(){

    expList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(2);
    Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(//resources here, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    expList.add(bmp1);
}

@Test
 public void testInit(){

    assertNull(EX.getListSize().get(0));    
 }

@Test
 public void testGetlist(){
     assertEquals("Result",0,EX.getListSize().size());
 }}
```

This is a simple testcase I am trying to setup, but I need to get access to resources from the test class `setUpList()` method. How do I access image resources for this Android Junit test? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.io/robolectric/index.html) to accomplish that.

For your code, you would have to put the following annotation:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class JamTest {
...
```

and then

```
 Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Robolectric.application.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

You have a look at more usages of BitmapFactory using Robolectric here: http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/5789498

Comment: RuntimeEnvironment.application(3.x) and Roboelectric.application are returning me null values. I have the RunWith annotation for class. What could be the possible reason